# Ruby Net::FTP Progress Bar

Tags: ruby, ftp

Does anyone know of a way to get a status update from ruby's Net::FTP library while downloading a file?  I am trying to implement a web interface that shows a progress bar for percentage remaining when downloading a file from a remote ftp server.

Answer (score 37):

For future reference - I stumbled upon a solution:

```
filesize = ftp.size(filename)
transferred = 0
p "Beginning download, file size: #{filesize}"
ftp.getbinaryfile(filename, "#{SOURCE_IMPORT_DIRECTORY}/#{filename}", 1024) { |data|
  transferred += data.size
  percent_finished = ((transferred).to_f/filesize.to_f)*100
  p "#{percent_finished.round}% complete"
}
ftp.close
```

Comment: This is an old thread, but, you can award yourself the answer. Good job.

Answer (score 5):

I expanded on the answers given by @smnirven and @theoretick to create a fixed size progress bar that fills up as it completes so that you can have a visual idea of how complete the progress is:

```
def getprogress(ftp,file,local_path)
  transferred = 0
  filesize = ftp.size(file)
  ftp.get(file, local_path, 1024) do |data|
    transferred += data.size
    percent = ((transferred.to_f/filesize.to_f)*100).to_i
    finished = ((transferred.to_f/filesize.to_f)*30).to_i
    not_finished = 30 - finished
    print "\r"
    print "#{"%3i" % percent}%"
    print "["
    finished.downto(1) { |n| print "=" }
    print ">"
    not_finished.downto(1) { |n| print " " }
    print "]"
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

ouput:

```
Executing gather for: ruby
Going to public ftp - ftp.ruby-lang.org
File list for /pub/ruby/2.0/:
ruby-2.0.0-p647.tar.gz

Downloading:    ruby-2.0.0-p647.tar.gz
100%[==============================>]
```

The key with this example is the print "\r" in order to rewrite the line.

Answer (score 1):

I built on @smnirven's excellent approach for a bit less noisy progress with 100-dot progression:

```
filesize = ftp.size(filename)
transferred = 0
notified = false

ftp.getbinaryfile(filename, full_local_path, 1024) do |data|
  transferred += data.size
  percent_finished = (((transferred).to_f/filesize.to_f)*100)
  if percent_finished.to_s.include?('.0')
    print "."  if notified == false
    notified = true
  else
    notified = false
  end
end
ftp.close
```

output:

```
[progress] Downloading CBSA boundaries...
..........................................................................
..........................
[progress] Finished!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update to the code to make the output little bit cleaner.

```
filesize = ftp.size(FILENAME)
transferred = 0
percent_finished = -9999

ftp.gettextfile(FILENAME, File.basename(FILENAME)) { |data|
  transferred += data.size

  temp = (((transferred).to_f/filesize.to_f)*100).round

  if percent_finished < temp
    percent_finished = temp
    STDOUT.write "\r Download progress: #{percent_finished.round}% completed"
  end
}
ftp.close
```